# How to put this image vertical?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have a div as the main wrapper, then an image-wrapper div as the image wrapper, and an .

What I want is that under certain lower resolutions (1300px for example), the image-wrapper div to stay vertically aligned. Now, when you see it, it is not vertically aligned. The top padding keeps the image-wrapper div stuck to the top, while on the bottom there is a large gap.

Here is the site:

http://namdarshirazian.com

It happens in the homepage. The central image.

Here is the ID of the main div:

```
#homepage-image
```

Here is the CSS of the three

```
#homepage-image
{
    padding: 20px 20%;
    border: 2px #CCC solid;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 540px;
}
#homepage-image div
{
    height: 495px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
}
#homepage-image div img
{
    width: 100%
}
```

And here is the markup of the element:

```
<div class="image" id="homepage-image">
                <div style="height: 520px; overflow: hidden;">
                    <img src="photo/homepage/image.jpg" alt="" title="">
                </div>

            </div>
```

The CSS are located in the style.css line 187.

I appreciate if you do a live edit. Thanks in advance

Comment: wouldn't this work http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="image" id="homepage-image">
   <div style="height: 520px; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;">
      <span class="keepImgVerCenter"></span>
      <img src="photo/homepage/image.jpg" alt="" title="">
   </div>
</div>

.keepImgVerCenter{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Hope this helps.